# Oracle - Sql - An entry with the highest value from other table

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I have 4 tables Car, Location, Time and Checkroom.

[image]

Car <--N: m -> Time
Checkroom is relational table.

I just want the date (from time),the location name and the car_name with the highest runtime.

Can anyone give a tip, how to solve the Problem?

Comment: Where is your code! what have u tried so far?

Comment: In the Oracle case, JOIN the tables, do ORDER BY runtime DESC, LIMIT 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try yo use this query:

```
select Time.Time_date, Location.Location_name, Car.Car_name 
from Time
inner join Checkroom on Time.Time_ID = Checkroom.Time_ID
inner join Location on Checkroom.Location_ID = Location.Location_ID
inner join Car on Checkroom.Car_ID = Car.Car_ID
where Time.Time_runtime = (select MAX(Time_runtime) from Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Oracle case, `JOIN` the tables, do `ORDER BY Time_runtime DESC`, use `FETCH FIRST` to get one row only - the one with highest Time_runtime.

```
select Time.Time_date, Location.Location_name, Car.Car_name 
from Time
inner join Checkroom on Time.Time_ID = Checkroom.Time_ID
inner join Location on Checkroom.Location_ID = Location.Location_ID
inner join Car on Checkroom.Car_ID = Car.Car_ID
order by Time.Time_runtime DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

`FETCH FIRST` is only available in newer Oracle versions.

Comment: The problem is that checkroom can have many diffrent car_id's. With your Query it will show only the car with the highest runtime ant not evry car with the highest runtime

Comment: I thought that was what you asked for! Do you mean you want top two cars if there's a tie? Or?

Comment: yes right! when der are 5 Entrys from 3 Cars, i want this 3 Cars with the highest runtime

Comment: I see. Well, go with Megatron's answer then.